# How to remove the handler in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, events

I'm adding some document to addhandler, where this script will execute on each time on ajax call.

But on the ajax result how can I remove the handler, where i tried using removeHandler but for the first time its getting affected.

Is any method to check whether the event is alive kill it.

Comment: I am confused about what you are trying to do...may be some code will help. Can you please some related code?

Comment: `addHandler` sounds to me like MS Ajax Framework, I'm I right?

Comment: yes MS Ajax only where i'm using on MVC Ajax Fom

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove an event handler with Javascript, you need to unsubscribe it this way:

```
document.getElementById("yourelement").removeEventListener("yourEvent", yourFunction);
```